# No volatile long? Should I use volatile in such a case?

Tags: c#

```
sealed class Counter
{
    private long _v = long.MinValue;

    public bool GetNextNumber(out ulong output)
    {
        long v0, v1;
        ulong max = ulong.MaxValue - (ulong)1;
        output = 0;

        do
        {
            v0 = _v;
            if (unchecked((ulong)v0 > max))
                return false;

            v1 = v0 + 1;
        }
        while (v0 != Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _v, v1, v0));

        output = unchecked((ulong)v0);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is a counter class, every time calling `GetNextNumber` will generate an unique number.

I use a cas loop to prevent the counter overflow.

The question is this line `v0 = _v`, since long cannot be volatile, is it possible `v0` gets a wrong value when many threads are calling the method in the same time?

If so how can I prevent it from happenning?

Comment: It seems that you can use [`Interlocked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=net-5.0) to improve thread safety in this case.

Comment: But I have used Interlocked.

Comment: Then why do you need volitile? `Interlocked` has `Interlocked.Read` method - you can use it.

Comment: Actually `Interlocked.Read(ref long)` does nothing on a 64-bit system. However, `Volatile.Read(ref long)` DOES introduce a proper memory-barrier.